# Relay for Figma plugin : Preview of generated code is correct but different in used in Activity

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, figma

I am currently testing "Relay for Figma", a tool that exports Figma designs to jetpack compose

I have a problem

After importing the Figma design and generating the compose code,

The preview when previewing the generate compose code is fine

[image: preview of generated code]

But when I was trying to use it, that is in Activity then the preview is completely distorted

[image: preview in activity usage]

And the same issue is happening when trying to run in device also

When this issue is happening ?

Figma project : https://www.figma.com/file/WynufomfvkuGjpw4BQjucw/Login-UI-Design-(Community)?type=design&node-id=0%3A1&mode=design&t=PajYAYOD77PAUECC-1